# Print vector in R's "vector notation"

Tags: r

I have a vector in R:

```
x <- c(25, 53, 37, 84, 883, 55, 55, 173, 34, 12, 30, 214, 25, 109, 277, 228, NA, 89, 133, 213, 309, 232, 67, 49, 75, 48, 34, 160, 101, NA, 12, 49, 40, 304, 18, 139, 371, 211, 17, 31, 111, 133, 279, 29, 50, 13, 94, 60, 24, NA, 211, 140, 26, 44, 72, 386, 19, 188, 986, 51, 52, 80, 108, 466, 515, 127)
```

When I print that vector, it looks like this:

```
> x
 [1]  25  53  37  84 883  55  55 173  34  12  30 214  25 109 277 228  NA
[18]  89 133 213 309 232  67  49  75  48  34 160 101  NA  12  49  40 304
[35]  18 139 371 211  17  31 111 133 279  29  50  13  94  60  24  NA 211
[52] 140  26  44  72 386  19 188 986  51  52  80 108 466 515 127
```

This makes it a hassle to copy values into a new vector.

How can I tell R to print the vector in R's own "vector notation"?

Like this (fake code), with or without the `c( )`:

```
> print.as.vector(x)
c(25, 53, 37, 84, 883, 55, 55, 173, 34, 12, 30, 214, 25, 109, 277, 228, NA, 89, 133, 213, 309, 232, 67, 49, 75, 48, 34, 160, 101, NA, 12, 49, 40, 304, 18, 139, 371, 211, 17, 31, 111, 133, 279, 29, 50, 13, 94, 60, 24, NA, 211, 140, 26, 44, 72, 386, 19, 188, 986, 51, 52, 80, 108, 466, 515, 127)
```

I believe there is a special command for this, but I forgot it.

Comment: Yes, function `dput()`. Type `dput(x)`.

Comment: Nice, thank you, @Pascal. Why don't you make that an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use function `dput()` for this purpose. With your example, it gives:

```
dput(x)
# c(25, 53, 37, 84, 883, 55, 55, 173, 34, 12, 30, 214, 25, 109, 
# 277, 228, NA, 89, 133, 213, 309, 232, 67, 49, 75, 48, 34, 160, 
# 101, NA, 12, 49, 40, 304, 18, 139, 371, 211, 17, 31, 111, 133, 
# 279, 29, 50, 13, 94, 60, 24, NA, 211, 140, 26, 44, 72, 386, 19, 
# 188, 986, 51, 52, 80, 108, 466, 515, 127)
```